# Magento: images are ingnoring the resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, magento

my problem is i am using stock in the channel for my magento store and all the images they are sending are just a link and there plugin is showing those images on our website. but the problem is there images are simply ignoring the resize set up for them.

thumb images are very small but the main images are very big and out of frame. same with product showing on home page (very small) and when we try to zoom in for product images, it show very tiny pictures.

and yes i am also using jQuery light box (which is working fine when we use to host images our self)

the whole problem is started when we sign up for stock in the channel and installed there plugin.

we have tried to edit every single file which could be related to images or jquery light box but no use. we also hired some freelancer to work for us but no one could sort the problem. we are in serious trouble here.

your help would be much appreciated.

Kindest Regards

Comment: Does the plugin support dynamic resizing? What plugin is it?

Comment: Hi this is the plugin: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sell-ingram-micro-techdata-100-other-suppliers-products.html

Comment: it just simply import the images in random sizes, and after that it depend on our theme. that how it wants to show that. but in our theme everything seems to be in order but this is still not showing right images.

Answer (score 0):

Find if the plugin is over writing any of your theme files and look for something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" 
       class="product-image">
       <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" 
       width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
 </a>
```

The ->resize(135) is setting the resize, next change that and your width and height.

PS: provide more information for a more accurate answer.

Comment: Hi Mike, how to check if the plugin is over writing or not? yes i can see these resize code in my file but it is totally ignoring that code. can you please tell me what else info you need and i will try to include as much as i can. thank you.

Comment: Did you install the extension through Magento Connect or FTP? One way to check is looking at the xml file from your extension. Go to your_theme directory (ie default/default) and look for the folder /layout (it will be next to /template) under /layout find the xml file related to your extension and see if you have something under  <catalog_category_default translate="label"> and <catalog_category_layered translate="label"> if you have a file for example  <block type="catalog/product" template="catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"/> find that file and edit it